# Sort table rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have an input in my table with a number.
What I want is sort on this number with jQuery and tried this code below.

```
<table>
  <tr>
            <td><input class="itemnumber" name="explodenumber[]" value="1"></td>
            <td><input class="explodeinput" value="1465" disabled=""><input type="hidden" name="exproductid[]" value="1465"></td>
            <td><input class="explodeinput" value="Remy Martin XO" disabled=""></td>
            <td><div class="deleteexplode">verwijderen</div></td>
        </tr>

  <tr>
            <td><input class="itemnumber" name="explodenumber[]" value="2"></td>
            <td><input class="explodeinput" value="145" disabled=""><input type="hidden" name="exproductid[]" value="145"></td>
            <td><input class="explodeinput" value="Wine" disabled=""></td>
            <td><div class="deleteexplode">verwijderen</div></td>
        </tr>
</table>




$('table').sort(function(a,b) {
  var data = $('.itemnumber').val();
     return $(a)data > $(b)data;
}).appendTo('table');
```

Comment: What do you mean, return `$(a)data > $(b)data;` ? This is not valid JavaScript syntax. It should be throwing an error.

Comment: You can't sort the table.  There is only one table element.  If you are wanting to sort the rows, you need to sort the rows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to be sorting Elements and not an Array or Objects. So you need to manipulate the elements based on the sort. Sort of two options:

A) When sorting, manipulate the elements during sort

B) Convert Table data to Object, sort the Object, re-draw the table.

Consider the following (Example B).

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.tableSort = function() {
    var c = $(this).index();
    var body = $(this).closest("tbody");
    var data = [];
    $("tr", body).each(function(i, r) {
      data.push($(r).clone());
    });
    data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
      var result = 0;
      // Asc Sort (1, 2, 3...)
      if ($("td:eq(" + c + ") > input", a).val() < $("td:eq(" + c + ") > input", b).val()) {
        return -1;
      }
      if ($("td:eq(" + c + ") > input", b).val() < $("td:eq(" + c + ") > input", a).val()) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    body.html("");
    $.each(data, function(i, r) {
      body.append(r);
    });
  }

  $(".itemnumber").change(function() {
    $(this).tableSort();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="itemnumber" name="explodenumber[]" value="1"></td>
      <td><input class="explodeinput" value="1465" disabled=""><input type="hidden" name="exproductid[]" value="1465"></td>
      <td><input class="explodeinput" value="Remy Martin XO" disabled=""></td>
      <td>
        <div class="deleteexplode">verwijderen</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="itemnumber" name="explodenumber[]" value="3"></td>
      <td><input class="explodeinput" value="145" disabled=""><input type="hidden" name="exproductid[]" value="145"></td>
      <td><input class="explodeinput" value="Wine" disabled=""></td>
      <td>
        <div class="deleteexplode">verwijderen</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="itemnumber" name="explodenumber[]" value="2"></td>
      <td><input class="explodeinput" value="123" disabled=""><input type="hidden" name="exproductid[]" value="123"></td>
      <td><input class="explodeinput" value="Absente" disabled=""></td>
      <td>
        <div class="deleteexplode">verwijderen</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```